# Is it possible to make a composed object in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scope, closures, shared-libraries, duck-typing

I'm building a site-specific library that I'd like to maintain as individual files but deploy with a unified API.

```
web = (function($){

  function web(opts) {
    this.id = otherLibrary.sniffID(opts.cipher);
    this.args = parseParams();
    if( opts.hide && opts.hide == true ) {
      $(`#${opts.frameid}${this.id}).hide();
    }
    return this;
  }
  function parseParams() {
    var sk = {};
    var x = location.search;
    var y = x.substring(x.indexOf('?')+1);
    var z = y.split('&');
    for (var i of z) { 
      m = i.split('='); 
      if( m[1] != undefined ) {
        if (['true','false'].includes(m[1]) ) {
          sk[m[0]] = eval(m[1]);
        } else {
          sk[m[0]] = decodeURIComponent(m[1]); 
        }
      } else {
        sk[m[0]] = true;
      }
    }
    return sk;
  }

  return minn;

})(jQuery);
```

But when I concatenate another file into the distro, I'm running into scope issues.

```
/** JS Helpers */
web.js = (function ($) {
  function debounce(func, wait) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function () {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
  };

  return {
    debounce: debounce
  }
})(jQuery);
```

In the client code, I do this:

```
var myWeb = new web({cipher: getCipher(), frameID: this.frame.id});
if( myWeb.args.localizeData ) {
  load('dictionary');
}
window.on('resize', myWeb.js.debounce(onResize));       // fails!
```

And, of course, the last line doesn't work - I'd have to use the static reference `web.js.debounce`, which means the containership implied in the key path is phony and it's not one object but 2.

Is there a pattern out there to do what I want, to have a single object with its API built from multiple independent files and assembled for distribution?  Maybe another way to say it: is it possible to duck type jQuery objects? And is there a way to share state across them, so, for example, `web.user.email` could reference `opts.fromAddress` passed in the `new web(opts)` statement?